# Relation between limits (colimits) and kernels (cokernels) in category theory.

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am new to the topic limits and colimits in category theory and I am interested in how limits (colimits) are related to kernels(cokernels). In which cases are they the same ? Can someone give me explanations or examples that help me to understand this topic better ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what $I$ is.

Comment: You're missing substantial information needed to define the (co)kernel. And it can't be any indexing category $I$. It needs to be two parallel morphisms so that you can construct their (co)equalizer. The category must also be additive so that you have the notion of a zero morphism. Please make these corrections to your question.

Comment: Kernels are defined in categories with zero objects as a limit over a certain diagram and cokernels are colimits over a different diagram

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks for this interesting fact. But I do not see why kernels (cokernels) can be defined in this way. Do you know an example ?

Comment: The kernel of a morphism $A \to B$ is the pullback of the diagram $0 \to B \leftarrow A$. The cokernel is the pushforward of the diagram $0 \leftarrow A \to B$. Pullbacks are always limits and pushforwards are always colimits

Comment: @leibnewtz This makes sense. Thanks !

Comment: @gian The only information you need to define kernels (cokernels) is the presence of an initial (terminal) object (see the diagrams above). If we have a zero object, then the zero map is the composition $A \to 0 \to B$, so no additiveness required

Comment: @leibnewtz You're absolutely right. Thank you for the correction.